# Binding a dictionary to a column of a datagrid

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagrid

Good morning to all, I have a tiny problem with my code. I want to use a `Dictionary` in order to create the columns on my `Datagrid`. Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Dictionary<int, string> parameters { get; set; }   
}
```

After several elaboration I've a cycle as:

```
string headerCol = "Test";  //just to test
foreach (string text in columns)
{
        var column = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = headerCol,
            Width = ActualWidth,
            Binding = new Binding(@"parameters["+headerCol+"].Name")
        };
        MyDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

but by cells are empty. How to bind the values of my **dictionary**?

Comment: What is `.Name` here?

Comment: For starters remove `class` from the property declaration `parameters`